# SQL WHERE IN causing issue

Tags: sql

I had the following portion of a where - note that `@TRUCK` is an input parameter of the stored proc:

```
WHERE TRUCK = COALESCE(@TRUCK, ATP.TRUCK) AND  ...
```

I like to pass

```
SELECT value from dbo.fn_split(@TRUCK, '~')
```

in place of @TRUCK as I like to pass it a ~ delimited list.

I tried using:

```
WHERE TRUCK IN (COALESCE(SELECT value from dbo.fn_split(@TRUCK, '~')),ATP.TRUCK)
```

but got the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: Try `SELECT dbo.fn_split(@TRUCK, '~') AS value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the subquery with `()`, and you've got the middle `)` misplaced:

```
WHERE TRUCK IN (COALESCE((SELECT value from dbo.fn_split(@TRUCK, '~')),ATP.TRUCK))
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure - but i would expect you would have to assign the 'select value from dbo.fn...' to a local variable and then reference the local variable in the coalesce(...)